# Centering a div based on another divs height

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div and in it i have two inner divs  to hold a logo and navigation.I have created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/ZBMhr/1/

I want the navigation to to be centered based on the  logo div.Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Center Depending on another div</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .container {
      margin-left:2%;
  }
  .outer {
      position:relative;
      height:100px;
      width:100%;
      background-color:orange;
  }
  .inner-left {
      position:relative;
      float:left;
      height:80%;
      width:200px;
      background-color:green;
      margin-top:10px;
      margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .inner-right {
      position:relative;
      height:40%;
      width:auto;
      float:right;
      background-color:pink;
  }
  </style>
  <meta charset="uft-8">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="outer">
         <div class="inner-left">
            <h1>Logo</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="inner-right">
            <p>Navigation</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your navigation div is 40% high, using

```
margin-top: 30%;
position: absolute:
right: 0;
```

should be sufficient, as 40% + 30% + 30% equals the full height.

When the outer container is positioned relatively, the inner elements can be positioned absolutely in relation to the parent.

If you want to give the element a fixed height, you can try this:

```
margin-top: 50%;
height: 40px;
top: -20px;
```

Comment: I think the margin top is the correct approach but its even simpler IMHO.The right div is 40px in height.If i were to center it inside a div 100px in height,that would leave us with 60px so 30px top margin and 30 px margin bottom.Since i have a 10px margin,top and bottom to the logo div,that leaves us with 80px.If i now try to fit in the navigation div which is 40px in height,that leaves us with 40px,so 20px top and bottom.If i now add 20px to the 10px,that is 30px margin top.I think its a lucky coincidence.

Comment: Both these appeoaches work for vertically centering elements in a variavle height container. If the centered div has a height in pixels, you need to use the second appeoach whereas if it is in percent you should use the first.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical centering with css has a few approaches. For this scenario, I'd suggest the negative top margin approach. You position the element you want centered absolute, top at 50%, and negative top margin to half the height.

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;margin-top:-20%;//20 is half height in this case
right:0;//float doesn't apply to positioned elements
```

You can see this working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nAAJ7/1/

Comment: I also have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/ByzCJ/ but i cannot say its perfectly centered.Just centers the navigation div.

Comment: Why not only use margin-top as the element has a height in percent?

Comment: I remember doing that a while ago and did not give the expected result.

Comment: Margin is relative to the node not the to the parent. So, if the nav div is 40% of it's parent in height, and you set the margin-top to 30% - that is 30% of the height of the navigation div, not 30% of the height of the parent.